# draw basic rectangular border in OpenGL for android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I just want to draw a simple rectangular border,
a filled rectangle is working ok but I can't find an easy way to just draw a border here's my Rectangle class.

Below is my rectangle class :

```
 package{

        import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
        import java.nio.ByteOrder;
        import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
        import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
        import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

        public class Rectangle {

            private float vertices[]={
                    -0.5f,0.5f, 0.0f,
                    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,
                   0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,
                    0.5f,0.5f,0.0f
            };


        // The colors mapped to the vertices.
        float[] colors = {
                1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // vertex 0 red
                1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // vertex 1 green
                1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // vertex 2 blue
                1f, 0f, 0f, 1f, // vertex 3 magenta
        };

            private short[] indices = {0,1,2,0,2,3};

            private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
            private ShortBuffer indexBuffer;

        // Our color buffer.
        private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

        public Rectangle(){
            ByteBuffer vbb  = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
            vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
            vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
            vertexBuffer.position(0);

            ByteBuffer ibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2);
            ibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            indexBuffer = ibb.asShortBuffer();
            indexBuffer.put(indices);
            indexBuffer.position(0);

            // float has 4 bytes, colors (RGBA) * 4 bytes
            ByteBuffer cbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
            cbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
            colorBuffer = cbb.asFloatBuffer();
            colorBuffer.put(colors);
            colorBuffer.position(0);
        }

        public void draw(GL10 gl){
            gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
            gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
            // Enable the color array buffer to be used during rendering.
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY); // NEW LINE ADDED.

            // Point out the where the color buffer is.
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer); // NEW LINE ADDED.
            gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike most 2D drawing APIs OpenGL ES has no concept of an automatic "stroke" for filled shapes. If you want an outline around a solid filled area you'll have to draw it yourself, e.g. using GL_LINES, or a thin strip of triangles.

Comment: well you see that's the problem i want to draw rectangular border on top of a  camera preview , the idea is simple just like a focus rectangle in camera application , i want to draw a safe region for for the user to place their receipt inside and crop out that area

Comment: What's the problem? You know the coordinates for the corners of your rectangle for your current draw, so just replace that with a draw of GL_LINES rather than GL_TRIANGLES (you'll need to correct the index buffer to link the correct points as lines, as that will be different to the triangle connectivity).